# Not getting smooth plot for particular dataset in pgfplot groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, tikz-decorations

When using groupplot to draw two plots with the common Y-axis, except for one curve the rest of them are sufficiently smooth. Even when data points are increased the steps in the plot stays. I tried to smooth it up, did not work. The data is quite smooth when drawn in other tools such as MS Excel.
The part of the preamble and code is given below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
    mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
            mark= between positions 0 and 1 step (1/20)*\pgfdecoratedpathlength with{%
                \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options
                \pgfuseplotmark{#1}%
            },  
        },
        postaction={decorate},
        /pgfplots/legend image post style={
            mark=#1,mark options={#2},every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}
        },
    },
}
\makeatother
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\DeclareSIUnit\radpersec{\radian/\second}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=2 by 1,
        y descriptions at=edge left,
        horizontal sep = 0pt,
    },

    ymode=log]
    \nextgroupplot[
    xmode=normal,
    width=8cm,
    height=10cm,
    xmin=-20,
    xmax=0,
    ymin=1,
    ymax=10000,
    xtick={-20, -10, 0},
    xticklabels={-20, -10, 0},
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1e1,2e1,3e1,4e1,5e1,6e1,7e1,8e1,9e1,1e2,2e2,3e2,4e2,5e2,6e2,7e2,8e2,9e2, 1e3,2e3,3e3,4e3,5e3,6e3,7e3,8e3,9e3, 1e4},
    yticklabels={$1$,,,,,,,,,$10$,,,,,,,,,$10^2$,,,,,,,,,$10^3$,,,,,,,,,$10^4$},
    xlabel={Imaginary part of wave vector $qL$},
    ylabel={frequency $\omega$ (\SI{}{\radian\per\second})},
    ]
    \addplot+ [color=red,thin, smooth, samples=10000] file{sem_complex_amm3.dat};
    \addplot+ [color=ForestGreen,thin] file{lmm_complex_amm2.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[
    xmode=normal,
width=8cm,
height=10cm,
legend style={draw=none, at={(0.8,0.3)}, legend cell align={left}, fill=none, anchor=north},
tick label style={font=\normalsize},
xmin=0,
xmax=3.1416,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=10^1,
ymin=1,
ymax=10000,
xtick={0,1.5708,3.14159},
xticklabels={0,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1e1,2e1,3e1,4e1,5e1,6e1,7e1,8e1,9e1,1e2,2e2,3e2,4e2,5e2,6e2,7e2,8e2,9e2, 1e3,2e3,3e3,4e3,5e3,6e3,7e3,8e3,9e3, 1e4},
%yticklabels={$1$,,,,,,,,,$10$,,,,,,,,,$10^2$,,,,,,,,,$10^3$,,,,,,,,,$10^4$,,},
xlabel={Real part of wave vector $qL$},
%ylabel={frequency $\omega$ (\SI{}{\radian\per\second})}, 
mark repeat={15},
]

    \addplot+ [color=red,very thin]    file{semamm_fifth_mode.dat};
\addplot+ [color=red,thin] file{AM_SEM.dat};
\legend{SEM};
\filldraw[draw=gray,fill=gray,opacity=0.2] (17,-50) rectangle (45,0);
\end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

Here sem_complex_amm3.dat is the data file for which the plot is not smooth. Please let me know if there is any other fix for this.[image]